# How to express "goto"s in a fuctional way?

Tags: algorithm, haskell

Take for example this diagram about some algorithm, where I have indicated with red arrows what I consider are "goto"s :
[image]

In the Wikibook about Haskell, particularly in the [Continuation Passing Style](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Continuation_passing_style) section, it says that the Continuation Monad can be used as goto statements, but I'm wondering if this approach could scale to complex algorithms.

To be honest, I thought that "goto"s were an antipattern, which bias me into thinking that there could be a better alternative. Perhaps "goto"s are just an antipattern in object oriented design?

Comment: What you have posted is not a program, but an abstract specification of a program (i.e. 'pseudocode'). As far as abstract specifications go, you are never obligated to 'literally' translate the spec to code - how you implement *any* feature (in this case, control flow) is completely up to you. Furthermore, even if the question is "how do I literally translate this pseudocode to Haskell" then it seems you already have an answer ("Continuation Monad can be used as goto statements") - but "does it scale" is entirely opinion based (what is 'complex'? what is 'scale'?).

Comment: As far as the titular question (to which, in my opinion, the body does not correspond at all), my answer (which is again, only my opinion) would be - a goto is translated to a function call. But, this isn't saying much - Haskell is a *function*al language, so basically everything can be expressed as a function.

Comment: You may find this question will get more interesting answers if you include a _short_ (real) code sample that uses GOTOs (presumably in some imperative language) and ask for a translation using CPS. In general, the problem with GOTOs is the same as CPS is the same as too many HOF - control flow becomes very difficult to follow.

Comment: @Alec what is HOF? I'll provide a sample code later today.

Comment: @user2407038 By scale I meant if the continuation monad has trouble when it is combined with other monads or if it is memory inneficient.

Comment: Consider reading something like [lambda the ultimate goto](http://repository.readscheme.org/ftp/papers/ai-lab-pubs/AIM-443.pdf) for an explanation of how to translate a goto-based implementation of an algorithm into one with function calls.

Comment: @LayGonzález "HOF" = "Higher order function". That being said, the algorithm above can be easily transformed into several loops and some smaller functions with some additional booleans and some early returns in your usual imperative language.

Comment: perhaps this will help https://gist.github.com/AndrasKovacs/6948657

Answer (score 2):

You may found these examples with `Cont` monad useful. They basically explain how you can define jumps in functional language:

https://www.vex.net/~trebla/haskell/cont-monad.xhtml

As it was mentioned in comments to your questions, `goto` has connection with CPS and CPS is basically what `Cont` monad about.